# Adding the static option to a variable

Tags: anylogic

Does anyone knows how can I add the "static" option when clicking on the advanced option of a variable? I have tried multiple things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the "developer mode" first, else AnyLogic hides this from you.

1. Open the "Tools" menu at the top
2. click on "Preferences"
3. Open the "Development" tab
4. enable "library developer mode" as below:
   [image]

Now, you can turn variables `static`:
[image]